# Unexpected Variable Scope in Python

Tags: python

```
name = "OutOfClass"

class MyClass:
    name = "InTheClass"
    var1 = [name for _ in range(3)]
    var2 = [name]*3


obj = MyClass()
print(obj.name)
print(obj.var1)
print(obj.var2)
```

When i run this code in vscode i got:
`for print(obj.var1)`

```
['OutOfClass', 'OutOfClass', 'OutOfClass']
```

and for `print(obj.var2)`

```
['InTheClass', 'InTheClass', 'InTheClass']
```

I expected the output of both codes to be the same and use internal `name` variable.
Why this happened???

I multiple run this code and result don't change.